# Sort a list of dot notated namespace strings into a nested JSON string c#

Tags: c#, json

How can I sort a list of dot notated namespace strings into a nested JSON string?

something like this.

```
var string1 = "example.string.1";
var string2 = "example.string.2";
var string3 = "example.anotherstring.1";
```

sorted into this.

```
{
    "example": {
        "string": ["1", "2"],
        "anotherstring": ["1"]
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Thanks guys! I was able to get it CLOSE to working using your answers.

with this list it works:

```
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "example.string.1",
    "example.string.2",
    "example.anotherstring.1",
};

public void Example()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        AddPartsToDictionary(dict, s.Split('.'));
    }
}

public void AddPartsToDictionary(IDictionary<string, dynamic> dict, string[] parts)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < parts.Length - 2)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(parts[i]))
                dict.Add(parts[i], new Dictionary<string, dynamic>());
            dict = dict[parts[i]];
        }
        else if (i < parts.Length - 1)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(parts[i]))
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                dict[parts[i]] = list;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var list = dict[parts[i - 1]] as List<string>;
            list.Add(parts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

result json

```
{
    "example":  {
        "string":  [
            "1",
            "2"    
    ],
        "anotherstring":  [
            "1"    
    ]  
  }
}
```

with this list it fails

```
var strings = new List<string>
{
    "example.string.1",
    "example.string.example.1",
    "example.string.2",
    "example.anotherstring.1",
    "example.string.example.2",
    "string.example.2"
};
```

I might have to sort the list or something, still working on it. Hope this helps with figuring it out.

Comment: Are the strings always only three levels deep (one.two.three)?

Comment: no, they could be any length

Comment: Do you need the last representation to be an array?

Comment: Will the depth of the levels be variable?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I would prefer an array, but it's not required. Yes the levels will be variable

Answer (score 2):

## Objects All the Way Down

If using objects (instead of arrays) all the time is okay, then this will work.

```
var strings = new List<string> {
    "example.string.1",
    "example.string.2",
    "example.anotherstring.1",
};

var result = strings.Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, Object>(), (acc, s) =>
{
    var level = acc;
    foreach(var segment in s.Split('.'))
    {
        if (!level.ContainsKey(segment))
        {
            var child = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            level.Add(segment, child);
        }

        level = level[segment] as Dictionary<string, Object>;
    }

    return acc;
});

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
```

The output has objects all the way down.

```
{
  "example": {
    "string": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "anotherstring": {
      "1": {}
    }
  }
}
```

## Arrays at the Last Level ([with a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WEb6nM))

If you would like arrays at the last level, then we need a precise definition of what defines the last level. For instance, does the last level always contain only integers? If so the following works.

```
var result = strings.Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, Object>(), (acc, s) =>
{
    Dictionary<string, Object> previousLevel = null;
    Dictionary<string, Object> nextLevel = acc;
    string previousSegment = null;
    foreach (string nextSegment in s.Split('.'))
    {
        if (Int16.TryParse(nextSegment, out _))
        {
            if (previousLevel[previousSegment] is Dictionary<string, Object>)
            {
                previousLevel[previousSegment] = new List<string>();
            }

            var list = previousLevel[previousSegment] as List<string>;
            list.Add(nextSegment);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!nextLevel.ContainsKey(nextSegment))
            {
                var child = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
                nextLevel.Add(nextSegment, child);
            }

            previousSegment = nextSegment;
            previousLevel = nextLevel;

            nextLevel = nextLevel[nextSegment] as Dictionary<string, Object>;
        }
    }

    return acc;
});
```

The output has arrays at the last level.

```
{
  "example": {
    "string": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "anotherstring": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  }
}
```

This array version will work only if the last level is only of `integer` types, which is what your original question required.

The more difficult case is to handle mixed `string` and `integer` types at the same level, which would have an input that looks something like this:

```
"System.1", 
"System.2", 
"System.Collections.1", 
"System.Collections.2", 
"System.Collections.Generic.1"
```

That requires a more complex algorithm. If that is the hidden requirement, consider asking a brand new follow-up question and linking to it in a comment to this answer.

Comment: This is an awesome answer I knew it could be done in way less code

Comment: very cool! It doesn't need to be an array, I was just wanting it to be cleaner than empty values.

Comment: I've added an edit with arrays at the last level @TheGeneral.

Answer (score 1):

I thought id have a quick go at this, its close but not exactly what you wanted. However i thought it might inspire you or someone else to have a try.

> **Disclaimer**, i'm not really a *Json.net* aficionado and this code is
>   fairly well.. unusual, to say the least

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WsIhiS)

---

**Given a list**

```
var list = new List<string>
   {
      "example.string.1",
      "example.string.2",
      "example.anotherstring.1",
      "example.anotherstring.2",
      "System",
      "System.Diagnostics",
      "System.Text",
      "System.Collections.Generic",
      "System.Linq",
      "System.Diagnostics.1",
      "System.Text.1",
      "System.Collections.Generic.1",
      "System.Linq.1",
      "System.Diagnostics.2",
      "System.Text.2",
      "System.Collections.Generic.2",
      "System.Linq.2"
   };
```

**Some Classes**

```
public class RawValue
{
   public RawValue(string key, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> values)
   {
      Key = key;
      Values = values;
   }
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Values { get; set; }
}

public class NameSpace : Dictionary<string, NameSpace>
{
}
```

**Some Helpers**

```
private static IEnumerable<RawValue> GetRawValues(RawValue value)
{
   return value.Values.Where(x => x.Any())
               .GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
               .Select(x => new RawValue(x.Key, x.Select(y => y.Skip(1))));
}

private static NameSpace GroupNameSpaces(IEnumerable<RawValue> groups)
{
   var result = new NameSpace();

   foreach (var group in groups)
      result.Add(group.Key, GroupNameSpaces(GetRawValues(group)));

   return result;

}
```

**Main Code**

```
var groups = list.Select(x => x.Split('.'))
                  .GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                  .Select(x => new RawValue(x.Key, x.Select(y => y.Skip(1))));

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
      NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
   };

var result = GroupNameSpaces(groups);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented, settings);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "example": {
    "string": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "anotherstring": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    }
  },
  "System": {
    "Diagnostics": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "Text": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    },
    "Collections": {
      "Generic": {
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
      }
    },
    "Linq": {
      "1": {},
      "2": {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

I think my downfall was having to use `NameSpace : Dictionary<string, NameSpace>` due to the fact i didn't know how to better serialise in *Json.Net*. Also without spending time on this, i couldnt figure out how to convert the last node to an json array. though i'm not sure if you will be able to if you think about it. However i'm **sure** this can be done better

Comment: @christopher_hustman also the json doesn't tell you if there is an exclusive namespace, like `system`